# ArcMap flashing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

ArcMap 10.2.2 has started blinking or flashing (Not Responding) but all of the toolbars are flashing along with the layout page, not in unison. Upgraded to 10.3.1 and it is still locking up and flashing. Has anyone heard of this?

Comment: Are you on Windows PC ? What kind of OS do you have ?

Comment: If you don't get any answer Try here ESRI GeoNet. https://geonet.esri.com/welcome

Comment: Could well be graphics card related as well.

Comment: What are you doing when it starts flashing? Does it occur immediately after starting ArcMap, or when you do something particular?

Comment: This is a problem that I think you should log with your local [Esri support](http://support.esri.com).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the same issue, but I have occasionally seen similar behaviour when interacting with a complex model in ModelBuilder, trying to access a ModelBuilder dialog in the process of something, e.g. starting up for a model run. Usually, giving it a bit of time, it stops. I suspect it has to do with the python tool validation, which can be quite complex and causes refreshing of (parts) of the dialogs of the tools in ModelBuilder.